# Einstein on a different BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein

I'm not pretty sure and I can't find information related on how to know if enabling Einstein on a different BU will increase the costs generated at an Enterprise level?

I know certain features when are enabled have not extra costs but others have like enabling Journey Builder for example.

The case use is really simple, Einstein exists on the PROD BU and I was thinking to run a couple of tests on the Non-Prod BU. Probably if there's a high cost for enabling it, definitely I would consider is a waste of resources.

Thanks in advanced.

I created a case as well to inquiry with support.

Comment: Using an app provisioned to an account doesn’t occur cost

Comment: Only using Product Recommendations on your web pages or emails or using Content Selection in your emails incurs Super Message charges. As EazyE states, simply enabling Einstein doesn't attract a fee, if it's already provisioned to your account.